# How to combine colour and linetype into a single legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, legend

I am trying to combine two legends of unequal length into a single length and am having some problems. I am using colour to represent 3 different populations, whereas I'm using linetype to show whether the population is infected or uninfected with particular bacteria.
This is what my code looked like to begin with:

```
ggplot(sds, aes(x= Temp, y=Fertile, group=Line, color=Population)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Fertile-se, ymax=Fertile+se), width=.1) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=Infection_Status))+
  geom_point()+labs(title="Fertility Thermal Limits", x= "Temperature", y= "Proportion of viable mating pairs") + 
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks=6)
```

and the resulting graph:
[image]

Following some advice from some other questions on here, I made several attempts to fix the issue, but was unsuccessful. First I tried manually labelling the legend:

```
ggplot(sds, aes(x= Temp, y=Fertile, group=Line, color=Line)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Fertile-se, ymax=Fertile+se), width=.1) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+labs(title="Fertility Thermal Limits", x= "Temperature", y= "Proportion of viable mating pairs") + 
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks=6) + 
  scale_colour_manual(name  ="Line",labels=c("Nowra +", "Nowra -", "Brisbane +", "Brisbane -", "Cairns +", "Cairns -"), values = c("blue", "blue", "green", "green", "red", "red")) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(name  ="Line",labels=c("Nowra +", "Nowra -", "Brisbane +", "Brisbane -", "Cairns +", "Cairns -"), values=c("solid", "dotted", "solid", "dotted", "solid", "dotted"))
```

[image]

while this had the desired effect for colour, for some reason I no longer had dotted lines for my uninfected lines. In attempting to reinclude them, I ended up with this:

```
ggplot(sds, aes(x= Temp, y=Fertile, group=Line, color=Line)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Fertile-se, ymax=Fertile+se), width=.1) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=Infection_Status))+
  geom_point()+labs(title="Fertility Thermal Limits", x= "Temperature", y= "Proportion of viable mating pairs") + 
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks=6) + 
  scale_colour_manual(name  ="Line",labels=c("Nowra +", "Nowra -", "Brisbane +", "Brisbane -", "Cairns +", "Cairns -"), values = c("blue", "blue", "green", "green", "red", "red")) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(name  ="Line",labels=c("Nowra +", "Nowra -", "Brisbane +", "Brisbane -", "Cairns +", "Cairns -"), values=c("solid", "dotted", "solid", "dotted", "solid", "dotted"))
```

[image]

The graph is back to normal, but the legend is still wrong. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(sds)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(sds, 20))`.

Answer (score 0):

Without your data or a representative example, I cannot give you a solution for your particular question; however, one approach you could take is exemplified here using the `CO2` built-in dataset.  In this example, you have a similar situation:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(CO2, aes(x=conc, y=uptake, color=Type, linetype=Treatment)) +
  stat_summary(geom="line") +
  stat_summary(geom="point")
```

[image]

Aesthetics in `ggplot2` are mapped to columns in your dataset.  The example above and in your own dataset, you have two aesthetics (color and linetype) mapped to two separate columns in your data.  Instead of trying to kind of "recombine" those columns into one to make one legend within the plot code, I would recommend *setting up a new column in the dataset itself*, then map to that new column and manually assign values.

In the `CO2` dataset example, this might look something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- CO2 %>% mutate(newcol = paste(Type, "-", Treatment))

ggplot(df, aes(x=conc, y=uptake, color=newcol, linetype=newcol)) +
  stat_summary(geom="line") +
  stat_summary(geom="point") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "red", "blue", "blue")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,2,1,2))
```

[image]

The idea is to create a new column (*newcol*) from concatenating the values of the other two columns (*Type* and *Treatment*).  The plot code is then modified to map `color` and `linetyp` to the newly-created column in the dataset.  This by itself puts everything into one legend, and you can modify the scale of the two aesthetics via `scale_*_manual()`.  In this example, I am just supplying a standard vector to the `values=` argument, but if you want to explicitly map a particular color or linetype to a particular value of the newly-created column, you can use a named vector.